# Finding radius of the first gear from a set of linear equations

Tags: java, algorithm

I got this problem in a code challenge and my solution did not pass all the test cases.

Input is an array locations discrete integers on a beam where a gear could be placed. The array is sorted and can have a maximum size of 20.

The objective is to find the radius of the first gear such that the rpm of the last gear is 2 times as much as the first one. It's possible that no such combination is possible. The minimum radius of each gear is 1.

Example:

```
Input [4, 30, 50]  Solution     r1=12, r2=14, r3=6  output:[12, 1]
Input [5, 10]      Solution     r1=10/3, r2=5/3     output: [10,3]
Input [4, 17, 50]  No solution                      output: [-1, -1]
```

I tried to solve it using Cramer's rule in the following way :-

```
Input: I0, I1, I2 ... In and Radius: R0, R1, R2 ... Rn
Eq1:  R0 + R1 = I1 - I0
EQ2:  R1 + R2 = I2 - I1
EQn-1: Rn-1 + Rn = In - In-1
Given : R0 - 2xRn = 0
```

The co-efficient matrix from the first example :

```
A = [{1,1,0},{0,1,1},{1,0,-2}]; Sol = [26, 20, 0]; X = [{26,1,0},{20,1,1},{20,0,-2}]

Det(A) = -1; Det(X) = -12 -> Soln: [12, 1]
```

This solution passed 3 of 10 test cases. I am not sure if my implementation or the logic is at fault. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Cramer's rule uses a *"matrix formed by replacing the i-th **column** of A by the column vector b"*. You appear to have replaced the top ***row*** of the matrix.

Comment: For example, if the input is [4,20,30,40], then `Det(X)` is the same whether you replace the top row of `A` or the left column of `A`. However, if the last three gears are not evenly spaced, then you can only get the correct answer by replacing the left column of `A`.

Comment: Hey .. I am sorry I typed it wrong. I have updated it now though. In the implementation it was correctly done.

Comment: In that case, I don't see anything wrong with the logic. What I would do is generate random test cases. Randomly choose the radius for each gear. From that, determine the location of each gear. Give those locations to your algorithm, and see if it generates the radii that you started with. Given that the algorithm fails on 7 of 10 test cases, it shouldn't be too hard to find a test case that fails.

Comment: Right that's a good idea I will try it. Do you think its the best way solve the problem ? I also tried and implemented that Gaussian row reduction method which also solved 3 test cases but different from the Cramer's rule though.

Comment: You don't need Cramer's rule or Gaussian elimination (at least not in the general sense). The system of equations is so simple and regular that you can simply solve it. For example, the solution for 4 gears is `3Rn=a-b+c` and the solution for 5 gears is `Rn=a-b+c-d`. Where `a` is `I1-I0`, `b` is `I2-I1`, etc. Once you have `Rn` it's easy to go back through the other equations to find the other radii.

Comment: yes you are right, with that approach the runtime would be O(1). Great answer. Thanks!.